# How to classify the cookies as third-party or first-party

Tags: cookies

As mentioned in the 'privacy internet options of IE' , how can anyone classify whether the cookies set are third-party or first-party ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They either come from the domain of the page being viewed or they come from a different domain via an image, JavaScript, iframe, etc.

If they are a different domain then they are third party.